# Summing digits of a singly linked list

Tags: c#, algorithm, linked-list

I want to familiarize myself with more data structures. As such I implemented a Node, singly-linked-list, as well as an algorithm to sum the digits of two such lists where each node contains the digits of a number. The order of the digits can either be largest digits first or smallest. Taking the number `1,234` as an example:

- Smallest digits first: the linked list will contain 4 as the `Data` property on the `Head` node, then 3, then 2, and lastly 1 (4->3->2->1).
- Largest digits first: `Head.Data` contains 1, then 2, etc... (1->2->3->4).

In the linked list I overrode the Equals method to permit value equality rather than reference equality for comparison with another list.

---

Algorithm logic: I first solved the algorithm manually and implemented the result in code.

Smallest digits first: Starting from the `LinkedList.Head` each nodes `Data` property can be sequentially accessed and added together. This process is repeated until the end of both lists has been reached. I thought of a Queue data structure but didn't see the need to traverse each list twice so omitted it.

Largest digits first: the position of the digits may not line up. Given a list containing 1->2 and another with 3->4->5->6 should produce `12 + 3456 = 3468`. I thought it best to access each node in the list to `Push` them onto a stack. After all nodes had been accessed this way, each digit could be `Pop`ed off to add their values together.

---

The logic for each type of list is duplicated as they are essentially checking the same conditions. I would like to eliminate this duplication to have the logic in one location. The thought crossed my mind of converting the largest digits first to a smallest digits first. Doing that doesn't feel correct however.

Below are my implementations.

---

Node implementation:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

    [DebuggerDisplay("{Data}")]
    public class Node
    {
        public Node(int d)
        {
            Data = d;
        }

        public int Data { get; }

        public Node Next { get; set; } = null;
    }
```

LinkedList implementation:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
    [DebuggerDisplay("{ToString()}")]
    public class LinkedList
    {
        public LinkedList()
        {
        }

        public LinkedList(int data)
        {
            Head = new Node(data);
        }

        public LinkedList(IEnumerable<int> values)
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    Head = new Node(value);
                }
                else
                {
                    AddNode(value);
                }

                count++;
            }
        }

        public LinkedList(Node headNode)
        {
            Head = headNode;
        }

        public Node Head { get; set; }

        public void AddNodes(IEnumerable<int> value)
        {
            foreach (var i in value)
            {
                AddNode(i);
            }
        }

        public void AddNode(int value)
        {
            AddNode(new Node(value));
        }

        public void AddNode(Node node)
        {
            if (Head == null)
            {
                Head = node;
                return;
            }

            Node n = Head;
            while (n.Next != null)
            {
                n = n.Next;
            }

            n.Next = node;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            var node = Head;
            while (node != null)
            {
                sb.Append(node.Data);
                node = node.Next;
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return obj is LinkedList other
                ? Equals(other)
                : false;
        }

        public bool Equals(LinkedList other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (Head.Data != other.Head.Data)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (OnlyOneNodeNull(Head.Next, other.Head.Next))
            {
                return false;
            }

            var thisNode = Head.Next;
            var otherNode = other.Head.Next;

            while (thisNode != null && otherNode != null)
            {
                if (OnlyOneNodeNull(Head.Next, other.Head.Next))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                if (thisNode.Data != otherNode.Data)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                thisNode = thisNode.Next;
                otherNode = otherNode.Next;
            }

            return true;
        }

        private bool OnlyOneNodeNull(Node lhs, Node rhs)
        {
            return lhs.Next == null && rhs.Next != null
                || lhs.Next != null && rhs.Next == null;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return 1473396059 + EqualityComparer<Node>.Default.GetHashCode(Head);
        }
    }
```

Algorithm implementation:

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
    public class SumLinkedListDigits
    {
        public LinkedList SmallestDigitsFirst(LinkedList ll1, LinkedList ll2)
        {
            var left = ll1.Head;
            var right = ll2.Head;
            var ll = new LinkedList();
            int carriedValue = 0;
            int onesValue = 0;

            while (left != null && right != null)
            {
                (carriedValue, onesValue) = AdditionValues(left.Data, right.Data, carriedValue);
                ll.AddNode(new Node(onesValue));

                left = left.Next;
                right = right.Next;
            }

            if (left == null)
            {
                while (right != null)
                {
                    (carriedValue, onesValue) = AdditionValues(0, right.Data, carriedValue);
                    ll.AddNode(onesValue);

                    right = right.Next;
                }

                if (carriedValue != 0)
                {
                    ll.AddNode(carriedValue);
                }
            }

            if (right == null)
            {
                while (left != null)
                {
                    (carriedValue, onesValue) = AdditionValues(left.Data, 0, carriedValue);
                    ll.AddNode(onesValue);

                    left = left.Next;
                }

                if (carriedValue != 0)
                {
                    ll.AddNode(carriedValue);
                }
            }

            return ll;
        }

        public LinkedList LargestDigitsFirst(LinkedList ll1, LinkedList ll2)
        {
            var left = StackFromLinkedList(ll1);
            var right = StackFromLinkedList(ll2);

            int previouslyCarried = 0;
            int onesValue = 0;
            Node node = null;

            while (left.Count > 0 && right.Count > 0)
            {
                var leftValue = left.Pop();
                var rightValue = right.Pop();

                (previouslyCarried, onesValue) = AdditionValues(leftValue, rightValue, previouslyCarried);
                node = PrefixValuesToLargestDigitFirstNode(node, onesValue);
            }

            if (left.Count == 0 && right.Count == 0)
            {
                return previouslyCarried == 0
                    ? new LinkedList(node)
                    : new LinkedList(PrefixValuesToLargestDigitFirstNode(node, previouslyCarried));
            }

            if (left.Count == 0)
            {
                return PrefixRemainingStackValues(node, right, previouslyCarried);
            }

            if (right.Count == 0)
            {
                return PrefixRemainingStackValues(node, left, previouslyCarried);
            }

            return null;
        }

        private LinkedList PrefixRemainingStackValues(Node node, Stack<int> stack, int previouslyCarried)
        {
            int onesValue = 0;
            while (stack.Count > 0)
            {
                (previouslyCarried, onesValue) = AdditionValues(stack.Pop(), 0, previouslyCarried);
            }

            var updatedNode = PrefixValuesToLargestDigitFirstNode(node, onesValue);

            return previouslyCarried == 0
                ? new LinkedList(updatedNode)
                : new LinkedList(PrefixValuesToLargestDigitFirstNode(updatedNode, onesValue));
        }

        private Node PrefixValuesToLargestDigitFirstNode(Node node, int value)
        {
            var newFirst = new Node(value)
            {
                Next = node
            };

            return newFirst;
        }

        private (int carryDigit, int onesValue) AdditionValues(int left, int right, int carriedValue)
        {
            int carry = 0;
            int onesValue = 0;
            int summed = left + right + carriedValue;
            if (summed > 9)
            {
                carry = 1;
                onesValue = summed % 10;
            }
            else
            {
                carry = 0;
                onesValue = summed;
            }

            return (carry, onesValue);
        }

        private Stack<int> StackFromLinkedList(LinkedList linkedList)
        {
            var node = linkedList.Head;
            var stack = new Stack<int>();
            while (node != null)
            {
                stack.Push(node.Data);
                node = node.Next;
            }

            return stack;
        }
    }
```
````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- I don't think exposing the Node class is useful. It should probably be mostly an internal class within your class (or at least package/namespace)
- `Node` could be using generics, so `Node<T>` instead of always having an `int`
- At least some of your `AddNode`-methods could simply be called `Add` instead. Because they're actually adding a number, a list of numbers, or something else that is not exactly a `Node`.
- Think about the current time complexity of `AddNodes(IEnumerable<int> value)` and think about if it's possible to improve it somehow. *(Hint: Yes, it is. A single `AddNode` operation gets more and more costly the more you add, but adding a bunch of them at the same time could be almost as cheap as simply adding just one)*
- `OnlyOneNodeNull` can be simplified by using the XOR operator: `lhs.Next == null ^ rhs.Next == null`.

Overall, good job :)

Comment: (For bools, I find `!=` clearer than `^`)

Comment: @canton7 That's also a good option yes. In this particular case I think it might be a bit confusing to mix `==`, `!=` and `==`, but it'd definitely be a valid option and might just be preference.